# Multiple material on a label!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I made a model of a cosmetics bottle with a label on it,

[image]

regarding my design the logo should be in Silver hot foil texture so I made the design picture as PNG.

Then applied it on the label then the silver material under it, then the last material should simple diffuse white material as the adhesive paper back

Now when I apply the three materials on the label, the silver foil material doesn't appears on the preview render but the paper back material do.

But when I remove the paper back material the silver foil appears, 
but I need them all to appears cause the are a transparent bottles not only what plastic bottle,

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's very confusing if you don't show any screenshot of your object + node organization

Comment: i showed up an image of my label with the silver foil material, the node are all of no problem in them, 
but my problem is only how to organize the materials on the label to be the face design and then from inside to be paper back and the silver foil to be appears only through the logo

Comment: Is the texture transparent?

Comment: yes the design texture is transparent correctly, but when the paper back material appears it's appears also through the logo but i need the silver foil to be appears through the logo.

Comment: You could split the sub layers, so you can change separately both colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've understood what you asked.
[image: render]

What you need then is a mix node for your label/Silver using the backfacing of your label's material. Here is the node setup : 
[image: node]
This allows you to use a specific material when your look at the back side of your material.

Comment: hey @Bithur 
thank you very much for your answer, yes it's exactly what i need the silver material to appears through the logo on the label and the back face of the label to be white diffuse. thanks a lot